# Angular 4 debugging CSS shadow dom and Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: angular

I have a small Angular 4 that for testing. During development, I want to see the styles, especially for troubleshooting shadow DOM things. I've created a component with the following CSS:

```
.level1Foo {
  background-color: #fea;
}
```

I see it exported, but as JS:

```
exports.push([module.id, ".level1Foo {\r\n  background-color: #fea;\r\n}\r\n", ""]);
```

I have two things to ask for:

- How do I see this in a human-readable form?
- Since shadow DOM is emulated, there is some `_ngcontent-cN` attached. I don't see it above. How / when is this generated and how do I look this up in dev tools?

Related: is there a way to display all styles in dev tools? When there are conditional styles such as this, it's hard to figure out why the style is **not** applied if they are "invisible".

Comment: Did you find any solution for this query?